# Code inside an equation environment is executed 4 times (or isn't it?).

Tags: equations, environments, code

I created a small example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[pdfstartview=FitH]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}
one line
\newcounter{test}
\[\text{\stepcounter{test}\bookmark[dest=whatever]{my equation}one equation}\]
counter value: \arabic{test}.
\end{document}
```

It creates 4 bookmarks but increases the counter only by 1. How is that (even logically) possible? Either this equation environment somehow executes the code 4 times (maybe first measuring the contents or whatever), then the counter should be increased by four. Or it only executes once, then there should only be one bookmark.

How do I get it to display only one bookmark? (moving it out of the equation is not an option since this happens inside a macro which at the same time marks the equation as target.)

**update**:

alright, egregs `\tbookmark` command fixed my minimal example. turns out it was too minimal. here is another one which went back to not working:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[pdfstartview=FitH]{hyperref}
\usepackage[atend]{bookmark}
\makeatletter\newcommand{\tbookmark}[2][]{\iffirstchoice@\bookmark[#1]{#2}\fi}\makeatother
\newcounter{nops}
\newcommand{\nop}{\stepcounter{nops}\raisebox{\ht\strutbox}{\hypertarget{nop\arabic{nops}}{}}\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\BookmarkAtEnd{\noexpand\tbookmark[dest=nop\arabic{nops}]{page \arabic{nops}}}}\x}
\begin{document}
one line
\[\text{\nop one equation}\]
counter value: \arabic{nops}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get only one bookmark. (I use TeX Live 2010 with latest packages)

Comment: I use miktex 2.9. I just started an update and will report back later. What additional information might be helpful to debug this?

Comment: the TeX primitive `\mathchoice` has four arguments corresponding to display, text, script and script-script style. When TeX encounters it it constructs all four and then inserts the appropriate one. So it could be a case of this primitive being used somewhere.

Comment: updated miktex, output unchanged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\text` uses internally `\mathchoice` (so jfbu was right), but `amstext.sty` redefines `\stepcounter` and `\addtocounter` in such a way that they act only once.

A cheap solution would be to define a special `\bookmark` command:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tbookmark}[2][]{%
  \iffirstchoice@
    \bookmark[#1]{#2}%
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

that will be free of the problem. Probably something that Heiko should take care of.

One might try also with `letltxmacro` (the redefinition must go after `\usepackage{bookmark}`):

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro{\orig@bookmark}{\bookmark}
\renewcommand{\bookmark}[2][]{%
  \iffirstchoice@\orig@bookmark[#1]{#2}\fi}
\makeatother
```

--- Added after Peter's edits ---

Any command to be used inside `\text` and which sets bookmarks or hypertargets should be defined in terms of `\iffirstchoice@`:

```
\newcommand{\nop}{%
  \stepcounter{nops}%
  \iffirstchoice@
    \raisebox{\ht\strutbox}{\hypertarget{nop\arabic{nops}}{}}
  \fi}
```

The AMS packages define `\text` using the conditional `\iffirstchoice@`; essentially, `\text{...}` is defined to become

```
\mathchoice{\firstchoice@true\textrm{...}}
           {\firstchoice@false\textrm{...}}
           {\firstchoice@false\textrm{...}}
           {\firstchoice@false\textrm{...}}
```

One has to remember that `\mathchoice` typesets all four forms and TeX chooses one depending on the needed math style; with `\iffirstchoice@<tokens>\fi` we are sure that the `<tokens>` are found only once.

Comment: How is `\LetltxMacro` different from `\let`?

Comment: @Aditya: When a command is defined with an optional argument, using `\let` to keep its definition is not safe at all. I believe this is a good question to ask.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks. I looked up the documentation of `letltxmacro` and it clearly explains why `\let` fails.

Comment: @egreg: thank you. how exactly does `\iffirstchoice` work? It's damn hard to google the things I get suggested here. ;-) I dont understand why the `LetltxMacro` package is needed in the second example. can't I just use a `\renewcommand` instead of the `\newcommand`?

Comment: you fixed my minimal example, but my production file still exhibited the faulty behavior. so please look at the new minimal example, i updated the question.

Comment: alright! renaming `\nop` to `\prenop` and then `\makeatletter\newcommand{\nop}{\iffirstchoice@\prenop\fi}\makeatother` fixes it.


i'd still like to know how `\iffirstchoice@` works though.